# Importing a CSV via PHP and treating duplicate lines as 2 entries

Tags: php, api, csv, fopen

For personal stats purpose, I check the last 500 sales through an API endpoint that sends me a CSV as a return, every 30 minutes.

The CSV is made like this:

| customerID | Timestamp | Sale | Commission | SignupDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3656323 | January 12 2022, 23:42 | 10.00 | 2.00 | January 23 2019, 12:34 |
| 1456324 | January 12 2022, 21:42 | 100.00 | 20.00 | December 15 2018, 21:34 |
| 1456324 | January 12 2022, 21:42 | 100.00 | 20.00 | December 15 2018, 21:34 |
| 4213516 | January 12 2022, 18:42 | 120.00 | 24.00 | July 25 2020, 13:34 |

Since I call the same endpoint every 30 minutes, I get the same CSV and most of the time the same lines reappear (I might have the exact same table 2 calls in a row)
As a result, I killed all duplicates by checking on the customer ID and timestamp. I thought it was okay then.

My problem is: As you can see in the example above, the customer, timestamp and amount are similar on 2 lines. This is not a mistake, its actually a double purchase. In my case, I will not take the second line because it will be treated as duplicate.I would like to have it included in my stats but I'm not sure how.

Is there any known solution to this kind of specific issue?

Actual code that I have: (data example may differ from what is in the code)

```
$handle = fopen('https://url.com/csv/?limit=500','r');
if($handle){
  while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) != FALSE ) {
    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
    $timestamp   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data[0]));
    $signup_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data[5]));
    $amount      = str_replace(".", ".", $data[2]);
    $commission  = str_replace(".", ".", $data[3]);
    $exists = money_line_exists($timestamp, $data[1]);
    if(($exists == 0) && ($amount != "0.00") && (is_numeric($data[1]))){
      add_new_money($timestamp, $data[1], $amount, $commission, $data[4], $signup_date, $data[6], 1);
    }
  }
}
```

And the money_line_exists() function is as below:

```
function money_line_exists($date, $id){
    $db = connect_db();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM money WHERE date_bill = '$date' AND user_id = '$id'");
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1 ;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Note: This is a repost for clarity and formatting.

Comment: _Small Point_  That CSV is not a csv, a csv is a comma seperated value TEXT file

Comment: `In my case, I will not take the second line because it will be treated as duplicate`, So, actually do you want to keep the second line or not?

Comment: So if you want to ignore the second sale, surely your stats will be wrong ??

Comment: Would it not be simpler to spot the dup and add the values togeter and then insert a row containing the right value for sales to this person

Comment: Do you control the API by any chance

Comment: Does the API allow you to ask for more fields that this request is getting

Comment: @ikhvjs yes. Modified my post to reflect that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly . Right. I want thats second sale in my stats, I'm not sure how to treat the CSV call though. I do not control the API unfortunately, nor can I ask for more fields.

Comment: So is it correct to say that duplicates 'within a single response' keep, duplicates 'across responses' remove?  You will need to keep a copy of the last response to compare with current response??

Comment: @AntG Correct. duplicates within I keep, duplicates across I remove. Keeping a copy is a solution but it sounds quite complex?

Comment: ___Something here is wrong___ You show a CSV, but not as a simple text file, but its layout does not match the columns you use in the PHP code

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes thats why I noted __data example may differ from what is in the code__ . The idea remains the same. There is no unique transaction column.

Comment: Actually, there is no way you can distinguish whether the data is duplicate or not if `customerID` and `Timestamp` are not the unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it correct to say that duplicates 'within a single response' keep, duplicates 'across responses' remove?

> Correct. duplicates within I keep, duplicates across I remove

If that's the case, do not insert the rows until you have parsed the whole response. That way you only query your database against previously inserted rows.

```
  $new_lines = [];
  while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) != FALSE ) {
    // ...
    $exists = money_line_exists($timestamp, $data[1]);
    if(($exists == 0) && ($amount != "0.00") && (is_numeric($data[1]))){
      $new_lines[] = [
         $timestamp,
         $data[1],
         $amount,
         $commission,
         $data[4],
         $signup_date,
         $data[6],
         1
      ];
    }
  }
  foreach ($new_lines as $line) {
      add_new_money(...$line);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Very straightforward and efficient solution. There is 1 case in which it will fail, if the first row of the last csv is equal to the last row of the new csv, then it will be counted as duplicate while it may be not; but I doubt it can ever happen.

Comment: If there’s a realistic possibility for that happening, I guess you could add a check to your exists method that checks that the existing row isn’t the last one inserted (that presumes you have some sort of ID or insert date).

Answer (score -1):

easiest solution wold be to add another data column (order id) to make sure lines are unique again.
There is no other way to not include OR include the row if both genuine double purchase and second read look alike.

Comment: This is really just a comment, there are places to put comments and it is not in an Answer

Comment: Correct. A UID of the transaction would be best, but I do not control the source